# mongodb schematic theory for feed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using a mongo database for a bunch of users, inside the collection i have the userid, then i have a nested collection (Array) of the things that the user has liked, or should show up in their feed etc. My idea is that when something they like changes their feed updates (i'll remove the past entry from days ago, and reinsert a new entry for today).

OK, here's the question/problem. This concept works well when one user likes something and then later a content element they liked gets updated... BUT, what happens if I have 5 million users that all like one content element (Say, an article) and then the element is updated... How, using mongo do I insert/delete new records from 5million records all at once... perhaps someone can suggest a better schematic...

Answer (score 0):

in this particular case - I will suggest a separate collection for that purpose

```
 col events/likes{
   _id,
   userId,
   action //add fields needed
 }
```

then if user id:1 is a subscribed to events from user id:2, we need to retrive documents from `events/likes` collection when user id:2

Makes this sense in your case?